# How to filter xml data using jquery?

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

```
  <Item id="419" rank="0.0000" date_added="2012-09-24T19:43:14" date_end="2012-10-15T19:43:14" uid="134333" price="  ,-" district="-1" district_text="Friend" cid="9" cid_text="Underholdning" img_height_thumb="433" />
  <Item id="418" rank="0.0000" date_added="2012-09-24T19:17:42" date_end="2012-10-15T19:17:42" uid="134332" price="  ,-" district="-1" district_text="Friend" cid="9" cid_text="Underholdning" img_height_thumb="254" />
  <Item id="405" rank="102.0000" date_added="2012-09-23T18:55:20" date_end="2012-10-14T18:55:20" uid="134331" price="  102,-" district="-1" district_text="Friend" cid="761" cid_text="Mote" img_height_thumb="280" />
```

This is sample xml data. And I am using this code to get xml.

```
 xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
 var items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Item");
```

//Want to add code

```
for (i = 0; i < items.length && i < 40; i++) {
var bRank = items[i].getAttribute("rank");
}
```

//want to add code

I want to filter all data rank which is greater then 0.
And I want to add filter only in this palce so my rest code won't change.
So how could i filter items variable and get filter values in other variable. so the loop don't get effected.
I can change the name of variables in for loop.

Please suggest me any idea for this.

**First Edit**

```
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        var items1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Item");

        var items = $(items1).filter('Item').each(function () {
            var bRank = $(this).attr('rank');
            var tempRank = bRank.replace("0000", "").replace(".", "");
            if (tempRank > 0)
                return this;
        });

alert(items.length);
        alert(items1.length);
```

Answer of both alert is 3.

but answer should like this for first alert 1 and for second alert 3.

but i am getting same response each alert.
please check and let me know your suggestion.
Thanks

Comment: Please check first edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/H9CQm/)**

```
var items = $('item').filter(function(){
  if(parseFloat($(this).attr('rank')) > 0)
      return this;
});

for (i = 0; i < items.length && i < 40; i++) {
   var bRank = items[i].getAttribute("rank");
}
```

You will need to add the xml to DOM to apply filter on xml. after that you can remove it.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/H9CQm/5/)**

```
$('#div1').html(xmlDoc); 
var items = $('#div1 item').filter(function(){
  if(parseFloat($(this).attr('rank')) > 0)
      return this;
});
$('#div1').remove();

for (i = 0; i < items.length && i < 40; i++) {
   var bRank = items[i].getAttribute("rank");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but in my case it's returning 0.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you need to put it in DOM to get the results. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for answer. still getting 0. I am using other js files. is this a reason for 0.

Comment: Do you have div1 in the html of page you getting the response or you are adding in some other element then div1?

Comment: Adding same div with same id.

Comment: But in html you have to have div tag <div id="div1"> </div>, you need to debug the code. As you can see in live demo example.

Comment: it's really worked for me. Can you please let me one thing. "xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;" this printing data like "object XMLDocument". coz this value filter loop is not working. how it will work?

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteredArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < items.length && i < 40; i++) {
  if(parseFloat(items[i].getAttribute("rank"), 10) > 0) {
    filteredArray.push(items[i]);
  }
}
```

`filteredArray` will then contain all items with `rank > 0`.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
I think append is not working. can you please check it and suggest me.

Comment: @PankajMishra Oops, sorry, it's `.push` not `.append`.

Comment: push is not working. if i use this "filteredArray.push(items[i]);"
Then I can't use for loop like that. I can't use this code "var bRank = items[i].getAttribute("rank");". Please check and suggest me.

Comment: @PankajMishra, can you post the exact complete code you are using?

Comment: for (i = 0; i < filteredArray.length && i < 40; i++) {
var bRank = filteredArray[i].getAttribute("rank");
}

Please check this code. This is not working if i am using push.